# nodejs create readstream with binary mode?

Tags: node.js, file, stream

I can open file in binary mode with python

```
open ('filename', 'rb') as f:
    for line in f:
        print line
```

how can I do this in node?

```
input = fs.createReadStream filePath, {flags: "rb"}
```

anyway, this is wrong

Answer (score 0):

> If no encoding is specified, then the raw buffer is returned.

[**fs.readFile(file[, options], callback)**](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_file_options_callback)

```
fs.readFile('filename', (err, buffer) => {
  if (err) throw err;

  console.log(`${buffer}: ${buffer.length} characters, ` +
    `${Buffer.byteLength(buffer, 'utf8')} bytes`);
});
```

> The Buffer class is a global type for dealing with binary data
>   directly. It can be constructed in a variety of ways.